# functions and saving a list

Tags: list, function, save

I get the error "'xlist' is not defined" How can I make my function "save" the list that it made?

```
def createlist():
    xlist=[]
    item=str(input("Item to add(\"N\" to quit)"))
    xlist.append(item)
    while item != "N":
        item=str(input("Item to add? (\"N\" to quit)"))
        if item == "N":
            print(xlist)
            break
        xlist.append(item)

createlist()

print(xlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not defined because you have it sitting outside of createlist() which is where you have defined it.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your `xlist` a global variable instead of a local one inside `createlist()` method, this should work.

The problem that I see is that you are trying to access a local variable from the method `createlist()`, in other words, the `xlist` only exists there.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Ty